# How do you Eager Load Category Fields with Pagination

Tags: categories, pagination, eager-loading

I have two category fields, `teamCategory` and `articleCategories`, on a news listing page that I'm trying to eager load. Problem is, when I add the eager loading it no longer outputs the categories. I should say right off that I'm not that experienced with Craft so I'm probably misunderstanding something.

From [the documentation I've tried the array syntax](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#accessing-eager-loaded-elements) but I'm either applying it wrong or there is a different approach for categories(?).

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('news').with(['teamCategory', 'articleCategories']).limit(25) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

{% for entry in pageEntries %} 

    {% set teamCats = entry.teamCategory[0] ?? null %}
    {% set articleCats = entry.articleCats[0] ?? null %}

    {% if articleCats|length %}
        {% for cat in articleCats %}
            {{ cat.slug }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if teamCats|length %}
        {% for logo in teamCats %}
            {{ logo.title }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

All the other posts that I could find were about more complex applications, I'm just looking for the basic function of eager loading a category field and then how to access it in the template.

I did try the non eager loaded syntax:

```
{% set teamCats = entry.teamCategory.all() %} 
{% set articleCats = entry.articleCategories.all() %}
```

Without eager loading that works, and I actually have another eager loaded field that I didn't include in this example (matrix) that works fine. It's just the categories that I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager-loading turns relational fields into arrays of elements (i.e. the same thing that happens if you do `entry.teamCategory.all()`), so your use of the bracket syntax is technically correct.

The problem is that you're doing

```
{% set teamCats = entry.teamCategory[0] ?? null %}
```

...which will set the `teamCats` variable to the *first* category from the eager-loaded `teamCategory` field (or `null`, if there are no categories in the array). Essentially, this is the proper alternative to `entry.teamCategory.one()` when the field is eager-loaded.

Which is why your `{% for %}` loops doesn't output anything – you're trying to loop on a single element, not the entire array of categories.

Since the `entry.teamCategory` and `entry.articleCats` fields are already arrays, the below would work:

```
{% set teamCats = entry.teamCategory %}
{% set articleCats = entry.articleCats %}
```

...although from looking at the example you don't really need those variables, so technically you could just delete those and do `{% for cat in entry.articleCategories %}` and `{% for logo in entry.teamCategory %}`.